# "walking for five o'clock every morning." "for"? Why not "at five o'clock"?

Tags: prepositions

I'm reading a book on philosophical puzzles and problems. At a certain point it reads (as an aside comment, not as part of a puzzle):

> "Before moving to Sweden, Descartes had a lifetime habit of staying in bed till 11.00 a.m.  After only a few months in the cold northern climate, **walking to the palace for 5 o'clock every morning**, he died."

Any special reason for using "for" instead of "at five o'clock"?  Can it be a pun? Am I missing something?

From Wikipedia - "Queen Christina of Sweden invited Descartes to her court in 1649 to organize a new scientific academy and tutor her in his ideas about love." The strange thing is that she wanted classes at 5.00 a.m. (!!!)

Some may label this question as "proofreading".  I understand it is specifically about prepositions, though.

EDIT

> - context - From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes#Death): "Queen Christina of Sweden invited Descartes to her court in 1649 to organize a new scientific academy and tutor her in his ideas about love. She was interested in and stimulated Descartes to publish the "Passions of the Soul", a work based on his correspondence with Princess Elisabeth. He was a guest at the house of Pierre Chanut, less than 500 meters from Tre Kronor in Stockholm. Soon it became clear they did not like each other; she did not like his mechanical philosophy, he did not appreciate her interest in Ancient Greek. By 15 January 1650, Descartes had seen Christina only four or five times. On 1 February he caught a cold which quickly turned into a serious respiratory infection, and he died on 11 February."

Some authors believe that walking to the castle at 5.00 a.m. in Stockholm, in January and February, contributed to his catching pneumonia and dying.

Comment: It is poorly worded.  And, in fact, the wording may be a part of the puzzle.

Comment: Surely a (lifetime - several months) [that's a minus sign] habit?

Comment: This was the down side of having a patron, as Decartes found to his cost. To have a brain like his, fettered to the whim of a monarch . . .it's enough to make one vote socialist.

Comment: An author who decided to experiment with maverick sentence structures without a care in the world that he would sound illogical.

Comment: @HotLicks It is completely clear and obvious to a British English speaker.  It is interesting that it isn't clear to a US English speaker of course.

Comment: @dorothy: Judgments about speakers of US English, based on an extremely limited sampling, are unwarranted and in fact a bit dismissive.

Comment: @Robusto I think you misunderstood me in at least two ways. First I wrote "a US English speaker" and second my intention was to be anything but dismissive. It was exactly to say that my comment about the obviousness to British English speakers wasn't to dismiss any conversation about its non-obviousness to non-British English speakers.

Comment: The thing that might differ between UK and US English speakers is the use of "for 5:00", meaning "to arrive at 5:00".  This isn't a common US construction.

Comment: Which book did you read this in and can you explain what part it plays in that book?  Was it from http://bit.ly/1a6v7ni ?

Comment: @dorothy   Exactly, dorothy.

Comment: So tiring to see the BrE/AmE thing when it is totally irrelevant. This might have been originally in French or Swedish and is clearly wrong.

Comment: Also, five o'clock unless specified usually refers to the afternoon and not the morning. It's just poorly edited. Is this a self-published book on philosophical puzzles and problems??He walked there for a 5 a.m. lesson or meeting with the queen.

Comment: @Lambie   [**This book**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=7Xq7AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT178&dq=%22Descartes+had+a+lifetime+habit+of+staying+in+bed+till%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiovN3ipaDhAhVRGbkGHSVIDgMQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Descartes%20had%20a%20lifetime%20habit%20of%20staying%20in%20bed%20till%22&f=false)

Comment: @Centaurus Well, it ain't English (UK); the author seems to be Canadian, or at least the publisher is.

Comment: @Lambie  If you read all answers and comments, you'll find that the native BrE speakers say it's idiomatic.

Comment: @Lambie This use of "for" is  quite normal in Canada.  I was surprised to learn that it isn't common among all English speakers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means he aimed to arrive at 5 o'clock. Had it read "walking to the palace at 5 o'clock" it would not have been clear if that was the time he left, some time during the walk or the time at the end of the walk.

Comment: Exactly. I do not understand why this obvious fact escaped others. It is quite normal (at least in Britain) to say something like *he gets into work for 6 o'clock  every morning*.

Comment: I've never heard this usage anywhere in the US. I certainly wouldn't count it "obvious".

Comment: Indeed, the US usage would be "gets into work *by* 6 o'clock" (or even "at 6" depending on your emphasis).

Comment: @MattGutting It is obvious to a native British English speaker.

Comment: @Lynn The use of "for" is subtly different. It implies that it is your aim to be there by 5 o'clock, not that you necessarily always succeed.  Actually, to be more accurate, it implies that you are *supposed* to be there by 5 o'clock.

Comment: I wonder whether the usage came into British English after American English separated, or dropped out of American English afterwards.

Comment: My wife does have a usage, "I want to get there for 8:00",  which is slightly different in that it explicitly includes the "wanting".

Comment: @MattGutting And there is also "seven thirty for eight” as a dinner invitation too of course :)

Comment: What's puzzling is how he sleeps until 11AM and still arrives at 5AM.  Must be quite a sleepwalker.

Comment: @HotLicks   Crazy as it  may seem, his patron princess wanted classes at 5.00 a.m. !!!        From Wikipedia: "Queen Christina of Sweden invited Descartes to her court in 1649 to organize a new scientific academy and tutor her in his ideas about love. She was interested in and stimulated Descartes to publish the "Passions of the Soul", a work based on his correspondence with Princess Elisabeth.He was a guest at the house of Pierre Chanut, less than 500 meters from Tre Kronor in Stockholm.

Comment: @HotLicks  Soon it became clear they did not like each other; she did not like his mechanical philosophy, he did not appreciate her interest in Ancient Greek. By 15 January 1650, Descartes had seen Christina only four or five times. On 1 February he caught a cold which quickly turned into a serious respiratory infection, and he died on 11 February."    Some authors believe that walking to the castle at 5.00 a.m. in Stockholm, in January and February, contributed to his catching pneumonia and dying.

Comment: @Centaurus - Like I said, how was he in bed until 11AM and yet he still got to the palace at 5AM?  The juxtaposition of the two sentences is contradictory.

Comment: @HotLicks Getting up at 11.00 a.m. refers to the time he lived in France and in The Netherlands.  He left for Sweden late in 1649 and died a few months later.  Queen Christina wanted him at the palace by 5.00 a.m. but I couldn't find how often, if ever, he made it on time.

Comment: @HotLicks The point is that he would like to have kept on sleeping in until 11am as he had always done previously but couldn't any more.  This killed him.  (Irrelevant question... why does no one upvote the questions here?)

Comment: @Centaurus - The point is, the original question places those two sentences back-to-back, without any context to clarify the interpretation.  If that is the extent of your source material then it is almost intentionally obfuscatory.

Comment: @HotLicks Does my explanation help? You can also see it at http://bit.ly/1a6v7ni for example.

Comment: @dorothy - I understand that he arrived at 5AM.  What's incomprehensible is how he did that while still remaining in bed until 11AM.

Comment: @HotLicks I already answered that didn't I? He *used* to stay in bed until 11am but now isn't allowed to by the queen who makes him be at work by 5am. Is that not clear?

Comment: Like I said originally, it's poorly worded, especially absent any context.  If indeed it's in a book of puzzles one would be justified in suspecting that the contradiction was a part of a puzzle.

Comment: @HotLicks It's not a puzzle!  It's just like saying that you were used to eating meat but it was quite a shock when you had to become a vegetarian. There is nothing complicated about it.  I will grant you that more context would have made it clearer but then.. google is our friend :)

Comment: But it's in a book of puzzles.

Comment: @HotLicks Did you read the link I pasted? It clearly isn't a puzzle. It's an explanation of how he died.  Not everything in a book of puzzles is itself a puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, this is a common way, in British English, of expressing that he walked **with the intent of arriving**   AT the indicated place BY the indicated time.

I have never heard this usage "walk...for" in the USA.

(If any other AmE speakers have heard or seen it in AmE, please comment.)

Comment: Well, if someone has a regular meeting ingrained into their routine, or just a lot of meetings, it's possible they would use "for", but with a possessive pronoun and omit the word "meeting". For example, _George bumped into Greta on the way to the conference room for his 10 o'clock_.

Comment: Yes, or with an indefinite article in American English at least: *I need to go, I have a 2 o'clock.* Left out and implied is (meeting/appointment/class/etc.)

Comment: I don't buy this at all. "We must be there for 5 a.m." would pass muster, walking there for it does not.

Comment: @Lambie He had to be at the palace for / by / at "5 o'clock every morning".  The fact that he was walking is incidental to the use of "for".